# Change title fontsize in heatmap.2 function?

Tags: r, font-size, heatmap

I am using the `heatmap.2` package to make a heatmap:

```
heatmap.2(as.matrix(FOOBAR.txt[rowSums (abs(FOOBAR.txt)) != 0,]),
          col=scaleyellowred,
          margins = c(10, 20),
          trace="none",
          xlab = "Comparisons",
          ylab ="gene",
          lhei = c(2, 8),
          scale=c("none"),
          symbreaks=T,
          cexRow=0.5,
          cexCol=.7,
          main="gene comparisons")
```

The output gives me a heatmap look like I want and looks good with the exception that the main title font is large. How do I decrease the font size of the title? I can't seem to figure it out. I can alter the font of the axis labels but not the title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`heatmap.2` use this statement to print plot title:

```
title(main, cex.main = 1.5 * op[["cex.main"]])
```

So You should set `cex.main` argument in `par` list. For example:

```
par(cex.main=0.5) ## this will affect also legend title font size
```